# ajax auto form submit with rails4

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, post

I'm using rails4.2.0 
in my e-commerce site, when a user submit his payment type, I want to redirect outside website. The flow is below.

1. a user choose payment type
2. use click submit button
   -- ajax (format js) --
3. redirect to outside website using post method

source of 2 and 3 are like ,

create.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:user,:url => { controller: "settlements", action: "settlement"},  remote: true, html: {class: :settlement_form}) do |f| %>
<%= f.radio_button :settlement_type, 0 %>paypal
<%= f.radio_button :settlement_type, 1 %>credit card
<%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => @user.email %>
<%= f.hidden_field :fee_type, :value => @user.fee_type %>
<%= f.submit "Submit", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }, class: "btn btn-warning" %>
```

settlement_controller

```
def settlement
  user = User.new(user_params)
  if user.save
    # parameters for outside website
    @payment_params
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

settlement.js.erb

```
var form = $('<form></form>',{id:"pay",action:'http://outside_ec_site_url/hoge',method:'POST'}).hide();
var body = $('redirect');
body.append(form);
form.append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'something', value: <%=      @payment_params[:something] %>}));
form.append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'something', value: <%=   @payment_params[:something] %>}))
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem, but I want to know better method.

changed settlement.js.erb like,

`$("#redirect").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'pay' ) %>");`

and created new file _pay.html.erb

```
<script>
$('<form/>', {id: 'paygent',action: "outside_website_url",  method: "POST"})
  .append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'something1', value: "<%= @payment_params[:somthing1] %>"}))
  .append($('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'something2', value: "<%= @paygent_params[:something2] %>"}))
  .appendTo(document.body)
  .submit();
</script>
```

then, it works.
Do you know any other method? Any idea is appriciated.